# hide browser context menu in jupyter lab, on MacOS / Firefox

Tags: firefox, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

One image illustrates the problem.
On a right click, jupyter lab opens its menu and then the browser (Firefox/MacOS) opens its own menu on top.

I'd like to prevent the browser from doing this. This wasn't happening prior to a reinstall and I don't know if I had a plugin for this before, or any custom setting, etc...

[image]

Comment: This is not supposed to happen; I cannot reproduce it on Ubuntu. Would you mind opening a [bug report](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug&template=bug_report.md) on GitHub providing the version information for your setup please?

Comment: @krassowski, there it is: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/11722